# Energy method in the Wave equation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

> Let $U\in\mathbb{R}^n$ be open, bounded, and connected, with a smooth boundary $\partial U$. Suppose that $u=u(x,t)$ is a smooth solution of the initial-boundary-value problem. 
>   $$
> \left\{ 
> \begin{aligned}
> u_{tt} - \Delta u + u^3 &=0\quad~~~~~~ \text{in}~ U\times (0,T]\\
> u&=0\quad~~~~~~\text{on}~\partial U \times [0,T]\\
> u(x,0)=0,\quad u_t(x,0)&=h(x)\quad~\text{in}~U\times\{t=0\}
> \end{aligned}
> \right.
> $$
>   Show that for each $t>0$,
>   $$
> \int\limits_{U} \frac{1}{2}\left[u_{t}(x, t)\right]^{2}+\frac{1}{2}|D u(x, t)|^{2}\, d x \leq \int\limits_{U} \frac{1}{2}[h(x)]^{2}\, d x.
> $$

**My Attempt:**

Suppose $E(t)=\int\limits_{U} \frac{1}{2}\left[u_{t}(x, t)\right]^{2}+\frac{1}{2}|D u(x, t)|^{2}\, d x$.
Then by using the Greens Identity we can get it to $\frac{d}{dt}E(t)=\int\limits_{U}u_t(u_{tt}-\Delta u)dx=-\int\limits_{U}u_tu^3$.

I was trying to show that this derivative is negative.
 so that $E(t)$ is decreasing. Hence $E(t)\leq E(0)$ that gives the answer.
But I don't see how should I prove that the derivative is negative.
Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can integrate wrt t, and use fubini theorem :

$$ \int_0^t \frac{d}{dt}E(\tau) d\tau = - \int_0^t \int_{U} u_t u^3 = - \int_{U} \int_0^t u_t u^3 = - \int_U \frac14u^4 - 0 \leq 0 $$

Comment: Thank you for the comment. But I don't get exactly what you said. Can you explain it a little further

Comment: I edited the post.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm missing a small point... But How do you get that last inner integral, $\int\limits_{0}^tu_tu^3=1/4u^4$?

Comment: Okay. I got it: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3630884/int-limits-0tu-tu3d-tau-frac14u4  

Thank you again