# $\int\limits_{0}^tu_tu^3d\tau=\frac{1}{4}u^4$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I came across this statement(which I don't understand) when reading a solution to a different problem. I think I'm missing a small point here but I don't see it. Can you please help me with an explanation.
Let $U\in\mathbb{R}^n$ be open. Suppose that $u=u(x,t)$ is a differentiable function from $U\times [0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ with $u(x,0)=0$ Then $\int\limits_{0}^tu_tu^3d\tau=\frac{1}{4}u^4$ where $u_t$ is the derivative with respect to $t\in[0,\infty)$

Comment: If you differentiate $\frac{d}{dt} \frac{1}{4} u^4 = u^3 u_t$.

Comment: Suppose we had merely $u(t)$, no dependence on $x$.  Can you do $\int\limits_{0}^t u'(\tau)u(\tau)^3\,d\tau=\frac{1}{4}[u(t)^4-u(0)^4]$ .  If so, what does $x$ do when you put it in?

Comment: This is true only if $u(x,0)=0$.

Comment: Thank you everyone. For the answers! And yes there was the additional detail $u(x,0)$. 
Well spotted @MarkViola

Answer (score 2):

Change that to one variable and remember how you used to do subtitution:

If $\;F(x)\;$ is a primitive function of $\;f(x)\;$ , and if $\;g(x)\;$ is a differentiable function, then

$$\int g'(x) f(g(x))\,dx=F(g(x)) +C$$

You can easily check this applying the chain rule on the right side. Well, it's exactly the same here wrt the variable $\;t\;$ ...

Comment: Thank you verymuch for the explanation. I appreciate it